# Using FlashMessenger with PartialLoop in ZF view scripts

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two questions related to the FlashMessenger view helper. Both questions are to do this code:

My action method:

```
private $_messages; // set to $this->_helper->FlashMessenger; in init()

public function loginAction() {
    // > login validation <

    // Switch based on the result code
    switch ($result->getCode()) {
        // > snip several cases <

        case Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID:
            $this->_messages->addMessage("That wasn't the right password."); 
        break;

        case Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS:
            $this->_messages->addMessage('Logged you in successfully. Welcome back!');
            $this->_helper->Redirector('index', 'home');
        break;
    }

    // >snip<

    $this->view->messages = $this->_messages->getMessages();
    $this->render();
}
```

My layout (Zend_Layout) view script:

```
<?php if (isset($this->messages) && count($this->messages) > 0) {
    print_r($this->messages);
    //$this->partialLoop('partials/messages.phtml', $this->messages);
} ?>
```

#### Why is the message not output the first time it is set?

I have a feeling this is to do with the messenger being stored in sessions but I'm sure it's to do with my implementation.

When I submit a bad value to my form I don't get a message until I either send the form again or refresh.

#### What is a good way of sending this to the `PartialLoop` helper?

The output of the messenger is something like:

```
Array(
    [0] => 'Message',
    [1] => 'Second message' //etc.
)
```

But this is no good for a `PartialLoop` as I need to get the message (which needs each message to be an array, containing a `'message' => 'Message string'` key/value pair).

Is there a better method instead of rewriting the array before submitting it to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [OIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513417/using-flashmessenger-with-partialloop-in-zf-view-scripts/513707#513707) I'd like to add that you can retrieve the flash-messages within the same request in which they where added to the FlashMessenger. In this case you'd have to use `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger::getCurrentMessages()`.

In your case you'd have to change the line

```
$this->view->messages = $this->_messages->getMessages();
```

to

```
$this->view->messages = $this->_messages->getCurrentMessages();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ill quote from [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger).

> 10.8.4.4.1. Introduction
>
> The FlashMessenger helper allows you
>   to pass messages that the user may
>   need to see on the next request. To
>   accomplish this, FlashMessenger uses
>   Zend_Session_Namespace to store
>   messages for future or next request
>   retrieval.

Basically, this means that yes you have to refresh the page to see the messages.

Edit for PartialLoop:

You could try this:

```
foreach ($array as $message) {
  $newArray[]['message'] = $message;
}
```

But you dont have to use PartialLoop. You could send it to Partial and loop it there. Or even loop it right there in your view.